# Looking for the lowest value in pandas row

Tags: python, pandas

I try to look the highest and lowest column

My Input

```
 id    Place A   Place B   Place C   
  1         67        87        76
```

My Output

```
 id    Place A   Place B   Place C   Highest   Lowest
  1         67        87        76   Place B   Place A
```

```
For Highest 'df['Highest'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)` works well, but For Lowest For Highest 'df['Lowest'] = df.idxmin(axis=1)` give error like this

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in idxmin(self, axis, skipna)
   8797         """
   8798         axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
-> 8799         indices = nanops.nanargmin(self.values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna)
   8800 
   8801         # indices will always be np.ndarray since axis is not None and

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py in _f(*args, **kwargs)
     65                 f_name = f.__name__.replace("nan", "")
     66                 raise TypeError(
---> 67                     f"reduction operation '{f_name}' not allowed for this dtype"
     68                 )
     69             try:

TypeError: reduction operation 'argmin' not allowed for this dtype
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens because you are reassigning the result of the `idxmax` to the same dataframe, so at the time you compute `idxmin` the dataframe contains an extra column `Highest` which is a string and cannot be compared to the other numbers. The solutions is just to assign to a different dataframe

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2['Highest'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
df2['Lowest'] = df.idxmin(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Like in the answer already said, since you run them back to back, the error in 'Lowest' is because of the just created new column 'Highest' which contains a string.

You could do it with `df.assign` in one go:

```py
df.assign(Highest=df.idxmax(axis=1), Lowest=df.idxmin(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   Place A  Place B  Place C  Highest   Lowest
1       67       87       76  Place B  Place A
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `dataframe` is large and you don't want to spend `O(N) in space` for creating a copy from the dataframe. You can do with `O(1) in space` and do in one line and creating two columns and insert value like below.

```
df[['Highest','Lowest']] = pd.concat([df.idxmax(axis=1),  df.idxmin(axis=1)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

```
id  Place A  Place B  Place C     Highest   Lowest
1   67       87       76          Place B   Place A
```